# How to include date and time picker in same dialog box and display the date and time in a single textbox in yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss format in Android

Tags: android

I need to include a date with time in a textbox in 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss format' using a date and time picker from a single dialog box (without using different dialog box for date and time picker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here [how to show dialog to pick date and time togather?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4428711/how-to-show-dialog-to-pick-date-and-time-togather)

And alternate solutions are :

1. [Date slider](http://code.google.com/p/android-dateslider/)
2. [Date time picker](http://code.google.com/p/datetimepicker/)
3. [Date Time Picker](http://code.google.com/p/ravindra-android-datetimepicker/)

And for formatting to show date and time is your own and easy task, I think now you can do it.